# Как написать функцию, которая проверяет , создаёт ли массив увеличивающуюся последовательность

Tags: c

Если создаёт, то функция возвращает True, если  нет - False. Использовать эту функцию в программе, которая спрашивает у пользователя целое число N  и массив из N целых  чисел.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int N,i,*aPtr;
int count(int N);
int main(){
    printf("N:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    aPtr=(int*)calloc(N,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d",&aPtr[i]);
    }
    free(aPtr);
    printf("result:",count(N));
}
int count(N){
for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if(aPtr[j]>aPtr[N])
            printf("\nTrue");
else printf("\nFalse");}
return N;
    }
```

Comment: Так а в чём трудности? Вам алгоритм подсказать? `for (i = 0; i  < N - 1; i++) { if (a[i] > a[i+1[) break; } return i == N;`.

Comment: он не корректно работает, False и True рандомно выводит, а надо что бы один раз вывело true или false для всего массива

Comment: Если подскажите, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count(int N) {
    for(int j=1; j<N; j++){
        if(aPtr[j-1] > aPtr[j]) return 0;
    return 1;
    }
```

Если есть хоть одна пара, где предыдущий больше следующего - последоваельность не монотонно растущая, возврат 0. Если до конца все хорошо - 1.